# JS split text into sentences

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to receive a lot of text (e.g. a book chapter), and create an array of the sentences.

My current code is:

```
text.match( /[^\.!\?]+[\.!\?]+["']?/g );
```

This only works when the text ends with one of [. ! ?]. If the final sentence has no punctuation at the end, it's lost.

How do I split my text into sentences, allowing for the final sentence to not have punctuation?

Comment: Does the final sentence have a line break?

Comment: add `\n` i.e new line

Comment: \n works only if there are no other line breaks in the text, which sounds unlikely.

Comment: You may include an example, you'll get more relevant answers

Comment: What about if you have abbreviations in your sentences?

Comment: I don't think you need to escape `.` or `?` inside character classes.

Comment: @flec if you can think of a regex way to allow abbreviations, please share! Otherwise I'm leaving that in the too hard basket.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `$` to match the end of the string:

```
/[^\.!\?]+[\.!\?]+["']?|.+$/g
```

Or maybe you want to allow whitespace characters at the end:

```
/[^\.!\?]+[\.!\?]+["']?|\s*$/g
```

Comment: Correct! Thanks, but actually you need to allow chars before the end of string `$`. So I made it `/[^\.!\?]+([\.!\?]+["']?|$)/g`, but I think it could also be `/[^\.!\?]+[\.!\?]+["']?|.+$/g`

Comment: @Mirror318 `/[^\.!\?]+[\.!\?]+["']?|.+$/g`  works great!

Comment: @Mirror318 You're right, mine was still missing the last sentence I think. Either of your suggestions should work. I've changed my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the characters in the text but

```
text.match( /[^\.!\?]+[\.!\?]+|[^\.!\?]+/g );
```

can do the job.

(If it doesn't work could you provide a few sentences what you can't match?)

Comment: I ended up with pretty much this, but also with the end-of-string `$` on the end: `text.match( /[^\.!\?]+[\.!\?]+|[^\.!\?]+$/g );`

Answer (score 1):

Depending on whether you need the punctuation of your sentences in your result you can just use "split"

```
var txt="One potato. Two Potato. Three";
txt.split( /[\.!\?]+/ );
[ 'One potato', ' Two Potato', ' Three' ]
```

Comment: I tried `split`, it's great in that nothing will be lost, but I do need the punctuation

Answer (score -1):

You can just use `[^\.!\?]+`, you don't need the rest:

```js
text = "Mr. Brown Fox. hello world. hi again! hello one more time"
console.log(text.match(/[^\.!\?]+/g))
```

Comment: Based on his original regexp, he seems to want to include the sentence-ending punctuation.

Comment: I know, why do you think my regex doesn't do that?

Comment: Because I ran the snippet.